# Creating a numbered list from a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking to convert a list of names in a text file into a dictionary, with numbers in front of the names as a list.

text file:

```
Adam A
Bob B
Charles C
```

The text file just has a name every line

Desired results:

```py
{1: 'Adam A', 2: 'Bob B', 3: 'Charles C'}
```

So far this is my current code

```py
numbered_dict = {}
namelist = open("data.txt")
for line in namelist:
    a=0
    a+=1
    numbered_dict[a]=line
```

and the output is:

```py
{1: 'Charles C'}
```

For some reason its only taking the very last name in the list

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```py
for line in namelist:
    a=0
    a+=1
    numbered_dict[a]=line
```

Each time through the loop you set `a` to 0 and then increase it to 1.

You have to initialize the variable outside the loop:

```py
a=0
for line in namelist:
    a+=1
    numbered_dict[a]=line
```

---

As a better tool, however, you can use the `dict` constructor and the `enumerate` function:

```
numbered_dict = dict(enumerate(open("data.txt")))
```

Comment: I like the one-liner but it won't close the file (I think). So you may have to do `with open() as`.

Comment: Python uses refcounting and it would detect that the file object is no longer in use and close it, so it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: how would you add 
```python
line.rstrip("\n")
```
into the one-liner?

Comment: dict(enumerate([line.rstrip("\n") for line in open("data.txt")))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
# Create a dictionary that will contain the file data
dic = {}
# Open the file and read it
with open('data.txt', 'r') as fd:
    # contain file in a list
    reader = csv.reader(fd)
    # Create a counter that will be the key of a line in the file
    count = 1
    for row in reader:
        dic[count] = row[0]
        count += 1
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `a=0` just above the loop, not within. Your code should be

```
numbered_dict = {}
namelist = open("data.txt")
a=0
for line in namelist:
    a+=1
    numbered_dict[a]=line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

with open('data.txt') as file:
    data=file.read()

numbered_dict=ast.literal_eval(data)
print(numbered_dict)
```

output :

```
{1: 'Adam A', 2: 'Bob B', 3: 'Charles C'}
```

You can read several other methods here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-dictionary-from-file-in-python/